# filter dataframe value using multiple dataframes

Tags: r

Is it possible to do this in R? Can someone guide me how to do this

For each Item-LC combination, from df2 based on the value of x months I need to filter the values accordingly from df1 based on x fiscal month.

df1

```
     Item    LC   Fiscal.Month  fcst
1   0S1576  MW92    2019-M06    22
2   0S1576  MW92    2019-M06        18
3   0S1576  RM11    2019-M06    12
4   0S1576  MW92    2019-M07    10
5   0S1576  RM11    2019-M07    10
6   0S1576  MW92    2019-M08    12
7   0S1576  MW92    2019-M09    10
```

df2

```
     Item    LC  xmonths
1   0S1576  MW92    3
2   0S1576  RM11    1
```

df3

```
Currentmonth
2019-M06
```

Suppose for 0S1576 MW92 I have xmonths=3 then from Curretmonth 2019-M06 it should select 3 rows as output from df1 and for RM11 we need 1 row:

Output:

```
     Item    LC   Fiscal.Month  fcst
1   0S1576  MW92    2019-M06    22
2   0S1576  MW92    2019-M06        18
3   0S1576  RM11    2019-M06    12
4   0S1576  MW92    2019-M07    10
5   0S1576  MW92    2019-M08    12
```

Comment: The issue with this logic is that if df1 contains more entries than the column `xmonths` specifies then you don't know which entries to pull, unless those number always match in which case you don't need `xmonths` and an inner join would suffice

Comment: df1 will contain more entries than column xmonths as it is the requirement. Entries to be pulled are next 3 from the currentmonth. Can I define a new dataframe also where I will specify all the fiscal months in order. Then can we select the no of xmonths from df1??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require(dplyr)
require(lubridate)



df1 <- read.table(text = 
  ' Item    LC   Fiscal.Month  fcst
1   0S1576  MW92    2019-M06    22
2   0S1576  MW92    2019-M06        18
3   0S1576  RM11    2019-M06    12
4   0S1576  MW92    2019-M07    10
5   0S1576  RM11    2019-M07    10
6   0S1576  MW92    2019-M08    12
7   0S1576  MW92    2019-M09    10') 



df2 <- 
  read.table(text = 'Item    LC  xmonths
1   0S1576  MW92    3
2   0S1576  RM11    1')





df3 <- read.table(text = 
                    'Currentmonth
2019-M06', header  = TRUE)




  df1 %>%  
    mutate(Currentmonth = df3$Currentmonth) %>%   ## adding current month 
    left_join(df2)  %>%   
    mutate(Fiscal.Month2 = gsub('M','', Fiscal.Month), 
           Currentmonth2 = gsub('M','', Currentmonth)) %>%  
    mutate(Fiscal.Month2  = paste(Fiscal.Month2, '-15', sep = ''), 
           Currentmonth2 = paste(Currentmonth2, '-15', sep = '')) %>% 
    mutate(Currentmonth2 = as.Date(Currentmonth2), 
           Fiscal.Month2 = as.Date(Fiscal.Month2)) %>% 
    mutate(max_month = Currentmonth2 %m+% months(xmonths)) %>%  
    filter(Fiscal.Month2 <= max_month) %>% 
    select(Item, LC, Fiscal.Month, fcst)  


  # Item   LC Fiscal.Month fcst
  # 1 0S1576 MW92     2019-M06   22
  # 2 0S1576 MW92     2019-M06   18
  # 3 0S1576 RM11     2019-M06   12
  # 4 0S1576 MW92     2019-M07   10
  # 5 0S1576 RM11     2019-M07   10
  # 6 0S1576 MW92     2019-M08   12
  # 7 0S1576 MW92     2019-M09   10
  #
```

Comment: What if I give my input as below it is not giving me RM11 in the output
where all the fiscal month are 2019-M06

Comment: I have edited the input. Can you please check as it is not working for this. I want all the values of upcoming x months be it multiple fiscal months

Comment: @AnshulS this answer is more robust, make sure you run the code and see the output after each step

Comment: What is the logic behind this: filter(month_rank <= xmonths)

And how are we assigning the ranks : month_rank = rank(Fiscal.Month))

Comment: I have edited the answer since, so this one takes the difference in months and imposes a 3 month limit. the old one just assigned a rank to each month from newest to oldest (after grouping by Item + LC).

Comment: But this is giving wrong output as for MW92, 3 months would be till 2019-M08 and for RM11 we need to get only 1 month i.e. 2019-M06